# Print out a random string between certain characters from a text file

Tags: python, file, random

Hi I have a text file named "fortunes" with a lot of data containing many differens quotes. Each quote is separated with the character "%". What I am struggling to do is to make a code that will print out **a random quote** out the whole text file, meaning that the random print should contain a string that is between the separator(%). Does anyone have any suggestions of an easy fix to this? As you can see I have started on something, but I am not sure where to include to random. function in all of this.
Thank you so much in advance

[image]

Comment: Read the file, split on the percent sign and use random.choice() to pick a random quote?

Comment: Could you please supply a small sample of your text file in your post as well as expected output? Also, your code and example input should be on your post, not as a picture.

Comment: Hi. The sample of the txt.file is highlighted in yellow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
import random

with open('./quotes.txt') as file:
    quote = random.choice(file.read().split("%"))

print(quote)
```

With a text file called `quotes.txt` that contains this:

```
Random quote
- HeyHoo
%
Foo is a great bar to start you off in the morning
- HeyHoo
%
Try sham-foo today! It'll make turn your hair into a bar of gold!
- ShamFoo™️
```

And it worked pretty well. You should [look into the split() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) & read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Split the file into a list around `%` and then just pick a random list element:

```
with open('fortunes.txt') as file:
  data = file.read()

quote = random.choice(data.split('%'))
print(quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `"in.txt"` is

```
%
A very deep quote.
  -- a very deep person.
%
An even deeper quote.
  -- an even deeper person.
%
An even deeper quote!
  -- an even deeper person!
%
```

Notice how it begins and terminates with a `%`. This program will randomly choose between one of `A very deep quote.`, `An even deeper quote.`, and `An even deeper quote!` and print it out (along with the author):

```
import random

with open("in.txt") as f:
    quotes = f.read().split('%')

# if file does not begin with nor end with '%' can exclude
# both of these "if not ..."
if not quotes[0].strip():
    del quotes[0]
if not quotes[-1].strip():
    del quotes[-1]

random_quote = random.choice(quotes).strip()
print(random_quote)
```

The program

- opens `"in.txt"` for reading.
- `f.read()` returns a string of all the text in `"in.txt"` (only call the function without arguments if `"in.txt"` is not too large -- by default, the sole argument of `read` is `size = -1` which means to return all the characters in the file).
- `split('%')` returns a list of the "words" in the string, using `'%'` as the delimiter. Since the optional second argument of `split()` is not specified, all possible splits are made.
- As we exit the `with` block, internally, the file is closed automatically for us.
- If the first or last element of `quotes`, stripped of leading and trailing whitespace, is the empty string, we delete it from the list. We do this to allow the file to begin or end with a `'%'`.
- `random.choice(quotes)` returns a randomly selected element from `quotes` (which will be a string).
- `strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespace from this string.

**Output** of the program will be one of

```
An even deeper quote!
  -- an even deeper person!
```

or

```
An even deeper quote.
  -- an even deeper person.
```

or

```
A very deep quote.
  -- a very deep person.
```